# $\epsilon$ rules for uniform and pointwise convergence.

Tags: definition

Could someone please provide with the $\epsilon$ definitions of uniform and pointwise convergence. I'm trying to really get my head around the differences between them (I do know the differences, but it would help to see them written formally in this way).

Comment: There is no $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ rule for *convergence*. $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ is for continuity.

Comment: haha, yep, I've just gotten so used to saying "$\epsilon-\delta$" that I forgot! i will ammend this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of functions $f_n:X\rightarrow Y$, where $X$ is a set and $Y$ a metric space. The sequence $(f_n)$ converges *uniformly* to $f$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $N$, such that for all $n\ge N$ and for every $x\in X$ : $d(f(x),f_n(x))<\epsilon$. Pointwise convergence is the same, but now you can choose $N$ depending on $x$.